# Enviar Formulario de Contacto con HTML y PHPMAILER

Tags: php, html5, phpmailer

se me ha presentado un problema al tratar de enviar el formulario de contacto de mi web a un correo gmail donde se almacenan todos los correos de dicho formulario.

Por favor pueden ayudarme a saber donde estoy fallando.

Formulario HTML:

```html
<form   method="post" action="mailer.php" name="cform" id="cform" accept-charset="utf-8">
<div class="row formulario">
   
 <div class = "col-md-6">
      <label for = "asunto" class="  fontverdana">Asunto  </label>
      <input type = "text" name="asunto"  id = "asunto" class = "form-control"  placeholder = "Ingrese su Consulta" required><br>
   </div>
   
 <div class = "col-md-6">
      <label for = "fullname" class="  fontverdana"> Nombre y Apellido </label>
      <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "fullname"  name ="fullname" placeholder = "Ingrese su Nombre y Apellido " required><br>
   </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
 <label for="email2" class="  fontverdana"> Email:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder = "Ingrese su Email" required><br>
      </div>
<div class = "col-md-6">
      <label for = "telefono" class="  fontverdana">Telèfono</label>
      <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "telefono"  name="telefono"   placeholder = "Ingrese su Telèfono" required><br>
   </div>
    <div class = "col-md-12">
      <label for = "mensaje" class="  fontverdana"> Mensaje:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder = "Mas detalles" required></textarea>
<br>
  </div>

    <div class = "col-md-12">
  <button id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class=" btn btn-danger btn-lg marginlastmin"> <span class="glyphicon icon-envelope"></span> <strong> Enviar</strong></button>
```

Script PHPMailer

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])){

$Asunto = $_POST['Asunto'];
$name = $_POST['fullname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';


$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'privado@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($email);
    $mail->addAddress('info.dnpcorp@gmail.com', 'client');     // Add a recipient
    

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $Asunto;
    $mail->Body    = $mensaje;


    $mail->send();
    echo 'El mensaje se envio de manera exitosa';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'No se pudo enviar el correo: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
}}

else
{
 echo "mensaje no enviado";
}

?>
```

Comment: Que error te muestra? o cual es el problema?

Comment: Esta página no funcionae no puede procesar esta solicitud en este momento.
HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

Como primer punto Google a implementado métodos de seguridad de inicio de sesión (como verificación a dos pasos) que generalmente no permiten autenticarte  por terceros y para ello debes desactivarlo para que PHPMAILER no te genere errores de envío de correo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si ya tienes resulto esto , ahora como segundo punto cambia la siguiente linea:

**$mail->isSMTP()**

por

**$mail->isMail()**

este método te permite enviar correos con la función [mail()](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.mail.php) de PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['email'])){

    $Asunto = $_POST['Asunto'];
    $name = $_POST['fullname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
    $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

    require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';


    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);           // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      // Enable verbose debug output
       //$mail->isSMTP();                          // Set mailer to use SMTP

    /*-----------------*/
        $mail->isMail();
    /*-----------------*/


        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;          // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'privado@gmail.com';// SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'secret';      // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';  // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;             // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom($email);
        $mail->addAddress('info.dnpcorp@gmail.com', 'client');     // Add a recipient


        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $Asunto;
        $mail->Body    = $mensaje;


        $mail->send();
        echo 'El mensaje se envio de manera exitosa';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'No se pudo enviar el correo: ', $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }}

    else
    {
        echo "mensaje no enviado";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ninguna de las 2 posibles soluciones funciona, godaddy tiene bloqueada la funcion php mail.